# Update totals in another table when changes made to the current table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2013

I have this table

```
ID       Name      Price

 1       John        12 €
 2       John        35 €
 3       Alex        15 €
 4       Alex        12 €
 5       James       10 €
```

I need a query that update a field in another table, summing up all the values in price field that have the same name. For example the results of the query in this case would be:

```
ID       Name      Price

 1       John        47 €
 2       Alex        27 €
 3       James       10 €
```

Comment: Do you have the ID column as auto increment in the new table?

Comment: You should avoid using key words as column names.

Comment: What are you trying to update?

Comment: @OverMind There is another table where I want to put the sum as I described. But if I modify the value in the first table, then the total in the other table must be updated as well

Comment: What version of Access?

Comment: @GordThompson Access 2013. By the way, the solution provided by fmbesteiro works but I need the values to be updated after the first time, not inserted every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Access 2010 and later we can use [Data Macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) to accomplish this:

[image: MacroList.png]

[image: AfterDelete.png]

[image: AfterUpdate.png]

[image: AfterInsert.png]

[image: UpdateOtherTable.png]

Comment: You can download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/266674/DataMacroExample.accdb).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tableName2(name, price)
SELECT name, SUM(price) FROM tableName
GROUP BY name
```

TableName2 is the second table you wrote on your question, while the tableName is the first one.

Notice this would ADD them into the table, not really update (since otherwise you'd have to insert all the data manually).

Comment: Well, this works but there's a problem. If I modify a value of the price field in the first table, I want that the price field in the second table change accordingly. With the Insert, it adds a new row everytime the query is executed, I want to update the existing fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,Name, SUM(Price)
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

OR

```
SELECT 
a.id, a.name, sum(b.price)
FROM 
table a INNER JOIN table b ON a.name = b.name
group by a.nid
```